# Twitter Typeahead Not Displaying Suggestions

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead, bloodhound

Hello I am trying to do a search on a database and provide autosuggestions as the user is typing using typeahead. The data is being returned as the user types but the autosuggestions are not showing under the input field.

```js
$(window).load(function(){
// Instantiate the Bloodhound suggestion engine
var employees = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (datum) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: 'https://www.example.com/prs/emp.php?query=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (employees) {
            return $.map(employees.results, function (employee) {
                return {
                    label: employee.label,
                    value: employee.value
                };
            });
        }
    }
});

// Initialize the Bloodhound suggestion engine
employees.initialize();
// Instantiate the Typeahead UI
$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: employees.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
       suggestion: function(data){
      return '<p>Name: <strong>' + employee.label + '</strong> | ID: ' + employee.value + '</p>';}

}
});
```

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" class="typeahead employeeName form-control" name="employeeName" style="margin:0px auto;overflow:visible;"  id="employeeName" placeholder="Employee Name">
```

I am getting the following response from the php file
 `[{"label":"Austin, Pickering","value":"155"}]`

I am not sure why It will not display the data. I have spent hours trying to figure it out. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code in the Snippet, it reported something you should take into consideration:
    Error: {
         "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
         "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
          "lineno": 45,
           "colno": 3
           }

I tried running your code on Eclipse:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    window cannot be resolved to a variable
    Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
    Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

```
at --------(Test.java:6)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking. The code snippet does not run on here of course becaue of the remote query to the database which i have changed the url to an example url.